# Where do I upload images used in pull request messages?

Tags: github

I want to make a GitHub pull request where the message contains screenshots. I know I can use the following markup:

```
![My screenshot](myscreenshot.png)
```

But where do I upload them? Does GitHub provide this service themselves?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Now, github provide image hosting, is not necessary to use an external service. You only need to drag&drop your imagen inside the comment box in the pull request and you are done :)

Comment: Why does github not communicate this awesome feature directly?!

Comment: Now, there´s a note with this info inside the PR comment box :)

Answer (score 3):

> Does GitHub provide this service themselves?

No.

You'd have to use an **external** image hosting provider such as

- http://imgur.com
- http://imageshack.us/
- ...

then use the full url to the image in the markup.

For instance, using `![notes marker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ZANN.png)` would embed the following image in the description or a comment of a pull request.

[image: notes marker]

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate your answer.